# The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<Describe>)

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I am trying to write a description class that will return an array of strings from calling describe through my interface.

this line: `return Collections.toString(items);`  is throwing the error in the title, and I can't understand why.

I know that I need to return type string and that items are not currently a string but I'm new to Java and not sure what to change.

trace error when run: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The return type is incompatible with Describe.describe()

```
package uk.ac.uos.assignment;

import java.util.*;  

public class Description implements Describe {
    private Collection<Describe> items;

    public Description() {
        this.items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String describe() {
        return Collections.toString(items);
    }

    public void add(Describe d) {
        items.add(d);       
    }
}
```

and this is my interface:

```
package uk.ac.uos.assignment;

interface Describe {

    String describe();
}
```

Comment: Hi Brennan, can you please add the exception stack trace you are getting?

Comment: Collections has no static method toString, so the method you are trying to call in your describe function, does not really exist.
If you call it as a Object function (return items.toString();), you will get rid of your error, but it isn't still doing what you want.

Comment: Please also add your Decribe Interface

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you want a `String` array returning the `String` representation of each of those *items* in your `Collection<Describe> items`.

Iterate over the collection and call the `toString()` method of every `Describe` item provided that the `Describe` class has its own implementation of `toString`.

This would get you a String for each of those items in your collection, collect them and return at the end.

```
public String describe() {
    List<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>(items.size());
    for(Describe item: items) {
        descriptions.add(item.toString());
    }
    return descriptions.toArray(new String[items.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, in the "describe()" method, I would suggest you do the following:

1) Create an empty String;

2) Iterate through the Collection and add every element, as a string, to the empty string you have created;

3) Return the String.

The basic algorithm I described above, now here's somewhat of an implementation:

```
public String describe(){

    StringBuilder y = new StringBuilder();
    items.forEach(i -> y.append(i.toString()));

    return y.toString();

}
```

Note: For this to work, your project must be set to use Java 8 or newer. If it is not, you will need to do a classical iteration through the Collection and then append each element to the StringBuilder.

Note 2: Your "Description" class must have its "toString()" method implemented. Before implementing it though, you should use an @Override annotation, just above the method:

```
@Override
public String toString(){...}
```